# Numpy matrix to array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I am using numpy. I have a matrix with 1 column and N rows and I want to get an array from with N elements.

For example, if i have `M = matrix([[1], [2], [3], [4]])`, I want to get `A = array([1,2,3,4])`.

To achieve it, I use `A = np.array(M.T)[0]`. Does anyone know a more elegant way to get the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: Ivnerse question: [convert a 2D numpy array to a 2D numpy matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443620/convert-a-2d-numpy-array-to-a-2d-numpy-matrix)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

If you'd like something a bit more readable, you can do this:

```
A = np.squeeze(np.asarray(M))
```

Equivalently, you could also do: `A = np.asarray(M).reshape(-1)`, but that's a bit less easy to read.

Comment: Little rant on my part...why does numpy have arrays and matrices as separate entities. It is so unpythonic IMHO. Thanks for this tip @Joe.

Comment: @Naijaba - For what it's worth, the matrix class is effectively (but not formally) depreciated.  It's there mostly for historical purposes.  Removing `numpy.matrix` is a bit of a contentious issue, but the numpy devs very much agree with you that having both is unpythonic and annoying for a whole host of reasons. However, the amount of old, unmaintained code "in the wild" that uses `matrix` makes it difficult to fully remove it.

Comment: Not to mention, true matrix multiplication was only added for arrays in Numpy 1.10, and is basically still in beta. This means that a lot of people (including myself) still have to use matrices instead of arrays to get done what we want done. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: Sparse matrices are fundamental for memory-efficient machine learning (e.g., `sklearn`). In fact there are different `sparse matrix` types in `scipy`, which allow efficient access via rows or columns. I imagine this may be an issue for merging the concepts of matrix and array. That said, I'm wondering whether there could be introduced a `sparse array` type as well and whether there are any plans for doing that. Any clues?

Comment: I think .flatten() works as well as .squeeze(), as long as you want a 1D array in the end.

Comment: array(..) defaults copy=True, so A and M are distinct if that's what you want [[ "asarray" behaves identically for matrix subclass ]]
*see @hpaulj* M.A1 same as np.ravel(M) which returns a view of M in A, shared memory - more appropriate for large matrices

Answer (score 151):

```
result = M.A1
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html

```
matrix.A1
1-d base array
```

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted answer, performance-wise, and simplicity

Comment: M.A1 is great, same implementation as "ravel" and "flatten" and in this case doesn't cause any data copy A thus remains linked to M which can cause surprises if A and/or M are mutable.
M.flat genuine alternative returning "flatiter" generator (read-only semantics)
np.squeeze(M) # gives a view removing dimensions of size 1, ok here too but not guaranteed to be 1-d for general M
np.reshape(M,-1) # is usually a view depending on shape compatibility, this "-1" is a roundabout way to do A1/ravel/flatten

Answer (score 13):

```
A, = np.array(M.T)
```

depends what you mean by elegance i suppose but thats what i would do

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following variant:

```
result=np.array(M).flatten()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
np.array(M).ravel()
```

If you care for speed; But if you care for memory:

```
np.asarray(M).ravel()
```

Comment: It would improve the quality of your answer if you explained why

Answer (score 7):

Or you could try to avoid some temps with

```
A = M.view(np.ndarray)
A.shape = -1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `Mv = numpy.asarray(M.T)`, which gives you a 4x1 but 2D array.

Then, perform `A = Mv[0,:]`, which gives you what you want. You could put them together, as `numpy.asarray(M.T)[0,:]`.

Answer (score 2):

This will convert the matrix into array

```
A = np.ravel(M).T
```

Answer (score 2):

[ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and [flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) functions from numpy are two techniques that I would try here. I will like to add to the posts made by [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/3338368#3338368), [Siraj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/39090501#39090501), [bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/20754955#20754955) and [Kevad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/30785041#30785041).

**Ravel:**

```
A = M.ravel()
print A, A.shape
>>> [1 2 3 4] (4,)
```

**Flatten:**

```
M = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
A = M.flatten()
print A, A.shape
>>> [1 2 3 4] (4,)
```

**`numpy.ravel()` is faster**, since it is a library level function which does not make any copy of the array. However, **any change in array A will carry itself over to the original array M if you are using `numpy.ravel()`**.

**`numpy.flatten()` is slower than `numpy.ravel()`**. But if you are using `numpy.flatten()` to create A, then **changes in A will not get carried over to the original array M**.

`numpy.squeeze()` and `M.reshape(-1)` are slower than `numpy.flatten()` and `numpy.ravel()`.

```
%timeit M.ravel()
>>> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 309 ns per loop

%timeit M.flatten()
>>> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 650 ns per loop

%timeit M.reshape(-1)
>>> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 755 ns per loop

%timeit np.squeeze(M)
>>> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 886 ns per loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Came in a little late, hope this helps someone,

```
np.array(M.flat)
```