# NumPy: Return a flat matrix where if the row == col, ignore value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to return a `numpy` flattened `array` of a `numpy` matrix where all the values where the `row == col` is ignored.

For example:

```
>>> m = numpy.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> m
matrix([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])

# Some function....

# result:

m_flat = array([2,3,4,6,7,8])
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array

Comment: @DreadfulWeather not really what I am looking for

Comment: @DreadfulWeather That question doesn't include the part about not including the main diagonal.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, good eye. Thanks

Comment: Is the matrix necessarily square?

Comment: in my case, it always is, so @unutbu's answer will do just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.eye` to create the appropriate boolean mask:

```
In [139]: np.eye(m.shape[0], dtype='bool')
Out[139]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [140]: m[~np.eye(m.shape[0], dtype='bool')]
Out[140]: matrix([[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]])
```