# Can NumPy's flatten() return a 2D array?

Tags: numpy

Can NumPy's [flatten()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) return a 2D array?

I applied `flatten()` on an array of shape `(12L, 54L)`, and I got a new array of shape `(1L, 648L)`. Is that supposed to happen from time to time? If so, in which cases does that happen?

I use NumPy 1.9.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike NumPy arrays, NumPy *matrices* are always 2D objects. So calling `flatten` on a NumPy matrix returns another 2D matrix, albeit one with shape `(1, N)`:

```
In [112]: x = np.matrix(np.random.randint(10, size=(12,54)))

In [116]: x.shape
Out[116]: (12, 54)

In [117]: x.flatten().shape
Out[117]: (1, 648)
```

If you convert the matrix to an array, then `flatten` will return a 1D array:

```
In [125]: np.asarray(x).flatten().shape
Out[125]: (648,)
```

Comment: Thanks, good catch, the issue was indeed it was a matrix, not an array. I should have converted the matrix to an array first ([Numpy matrix to array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3337301/395857)), or directly use  [numpy.matrix.A1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html#numpy.matrix.A1).