# matrix to the power of a column of a dense matrix using numpy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to obtain all the values in a matrix beta VxK to the power of all the values in a column Vx1 that is part of a dense matrix VxN. So each value in beta should be to the power of the corresponding line in the column and this should be done for all K columns in beta. When I use np.power on python for a practice numpy array for beta using:

```
np.power(head_beta.T, head_matrix[:,0])
```

I am able to obtain the results I want. The dimensions are (3, 10) for beta and (10,) for head_matrix[:,0] where in this case 3=K and 10=V.

However, if I do this on my actual matrix, which was obtained by using

```
matrix=csc_matrix((data,(row,col)), shape=(30784,72407) ).todense()
```

where data, row, and col are arrays, I am unable to do the same operation:

```
np.power(beta.T, matrix[:,0])
```

where the dimensions are (10, 30784) for beta and (30784, 1) for matrix where in this case 10=K and 30784=V. I get the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9f55d4cb9c63> in <module>()
----> 1 np.power(beta.T, matrix[:,0])

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,30784) (30784,1) `
```

It seems that the difference is that matrix is a matrix (length,1) and head_matrix is actually a numpy array (length,) that I created. How can I do this same operation with the column of a dense matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In the problem case it can't broadcast `(10,30784)` and  `(30784,1)`.  As you note it works when `(10,N)` is used with `(N,)`.  That's because it can expand the `(N,)` to `(1,N)` and on to `(10,N)`.

```
M = sparse.csr_matrix(...).todense()
```

is `np.matrix` which is always 2d, so `M(:,0)` is `(N,1)`. There are several solutons.

```
np.power(beta.T, M[:,0].T)  # change to a (1,N)
np.power(beta, M[:,0])      # line up the expandable dimensions
```

convert the sparse matrix to an array:

```
A = sparse.....toarray()
np.power(beta.T, A[:,0])
```

`M[:,0].squeeze()` and `M[:,0].ravel()` both produce a `(1,N)` matrix. So does `M[:,0].reshape(-1)`.  That 2d quality is persistent, as long as it returns a `matrix`.

`M[:,0].A1` produces a (N,) array

From a while back: [Numpy matrix to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array)

Comment: Will your fix `np.power(beta, M[:,0])` give the the same result ? Should it not be `np.power(beta, M[:,0]).T` to compensate the modification `beta` instead of `beta.T`?

Comment: Yes, `T` after to exactly match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `squeeze` method on arrays to get rid of this extra dimension.
So
`np.power(beta.T, matrix[:,0].squeeze())` should do the trick.

Comment: Technically with a `np.matrix` `squeeze` doesn't get rid of the extra dimension, it just changes the shape to `(1,N)`, like `ravel`.