# scipy sparse matrix division

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have been trying to divide a python scipy sparse matrix by a vector sum of its rows. Here is my code

```
sparse_mat = bsr_matrix((l_data, (l_row, l_col)), dtype=float)
sparse_mat = sparse_mat / (sparse_mat.sum(axis = 1)[:,None])
```

However, it throws an error no matter how I try it

```
sparse_mat = sparse_mat / (sparse_mat.sum(axis = 1)[:,None])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 381, in __div__
return self.__truediv__(other)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 427, in __truediv__
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Anyone with an idea of where I am going wrong?

Comment: The division calls the true_division, which is an element-wise division. This seems not to be implemented for more than one value. So, most probably, the result of `(sparse_mat.sum(axis = 1)[:,None]` is not a single number.

Comment: @Dschoni Yes, the result is a vector and my aim is to divide each element in each row of the sparse matrix with the sum of the row elements. So if M=[[2,4],[1,2]], I want to get Ans=[[2/6, 4/6],[1/3, 2/3]].

Comment: Have you tried `sparse_mat = sparse_mat*(1 / (sparse_mat.sum(axis = 1)[:,None]))`.  It seems the division of sparse matrices is the problem.  You may also have to convert the divisor to a dense array `sparse_mat = sparse_mat*(1 / (sparse_mat.sum(axis = 1).toarray()[:,None]))`

Comment: @uchman21 Please provide a small self contained example. This problem might be related to the data you put into the matrix. (Or it might be that your scipy is too old - sparse matrix division as I tried it works on Python 3 and scipy 0.18.)

Comment: I am using python 2.7.13 with scipy 0.18. The matrix is just a simple sparse matrix of 232 x 232

Comment: I wonder if this a Py2 issue.  I can do the division in Py3 without problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can circumvent the problem by creating a sparse diagonal matrix from the reciprocals of your row sums and then multiplying it with your matrix. In the product the diagonal matrix goes left and your matrix goes right.

Example:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 5, 3, 0, 7],
       [1, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0]])
>>> b = sparse.bsr_matrix(a)
>>> 
>>> c = sparse.diags(1/b.sum(axis=1).A.ravel())
>>> # on older scipy versions the offsets parameter (default 0)
... # is a required argument, thus
... # c = sparse.diags(1/b.sum(axis=1).A.ravel(), 0)
...
>>> a/a.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.9       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.1       ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.125     ,  0.        ,  0.3125    ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5625    ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.375     ,  0.20833333,  0.125     ,  0.        ,  0.29166667],
       [ 0.05555556,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.44444444,  0.5       ,  0.        ]])
>>> (c @ b).todense() # on Python < 3.5 replace c @ b with c.dot(b)
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.9       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.1       ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.125     ,  0.        ,  0.3125    ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5625    ],
        [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.375     ,  0.20833333,  0.125     ,  0.        ,  0.29166667],
        [ 0.05555556,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.44444444,  0.5       ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it give out error  

elem_sum = csc_matrix((1/sparse_mat.sum(axis = -1).A.ravel(), numpy.arange(sparse_mat.shape[0]), numpy.arange(sparse_mat.shape[0]+1)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 548, in sum
    return spmatrix.sum(self,axis)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 629, in sum
    raise ValueError("axis out of bounds")
ValueError: axis out of bounds

Comment: @uchman21 Strange, try `axis = 1` then, that seemed to work in your code.

Comment: yes that work. However, for me I needed to make it something like
c = sparse.diags(1/b.sum(axis=1).A.ravel(),0) to specify the main diagonal for it to finally work. Please add that to you answer.

Comment: `b.sum(axis=1).A1` should work.  The `sum` produces a np.matrix`,which has a `A1`property.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20765358/901925

Answer (score 4):

Per [this message](http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/Sparse-matrix-division-by-vector-td5437.html), to keep the matrix sparse, you access the *data* values and use the (nonzero) indices:

```
sums = np.asarray(A.sum(axis=1)).squeeze()  # this is dense
A.data /= sums[A.nonzero()[0]]
```

If dividing by the nonzero row mean instead of the sum, one can

```
nnz = A.getnnz(axis=1)  # this is also dense
means = sums / nnz
A.data /= means[A.nonzero()[0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something funny is going on.  I have no problem performing the element division.  I wonder if it's a Py2 issue.  I'm using Py3.

```
In [1022]: A=sparse.bsr_matrix([[2,4],[1,2]])
In [1023]: A
Out[1023]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>
In [1024]: A.A
Out[1024]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
In [1025]: A.sum(axis=1)
Out[1025]: 
matrix([[6],
        [3]], dtype=int32)
In [1026]: A/A.sum(axis=1)
Out[1026]: 
matrix([[ 0.33333333,  0.66666667],
        [ 0.33333333,  0.66666667]])
```

or to try the other example:

```
In [1027]: b=sparse.bsr_matrix([[0, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      ...:        [2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9],
      ...:        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ...:        [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      ...:        [0, 9, 5, 3, 0, 7],
      ...:        [1, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0]])
In [1028]: b
Out[1028]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 14 stored elements (blocksize = 1x1) in Block Sparse Row format>
In [1029]: b.sum(axis=1)
Out[1029]: 
matrix([[10],
        [16],
        [ 2],
        [ 2],
        [24],
        [18]], dtype=int32)
In [1030]: b/b.sum(axis=1)
Out[1030]: 
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.9       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.1       , 0.        ],
        [ 0.125     ,  0.        ,  0.3125    ,  0.        ,  0.        , 0.5625    ],
 ....
        [ 0.05555556,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.44444444,  0.5       ,     0.        ]])
```

The result of this sparse/dense is also dense, where as the `c*b` (`c` is the sparse diagonal) is sparse.

```
In [1039]: c*b
Out[1039]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 14 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The sparse sum is a dense matrix. It is 2d, so there's no need to expand it dimensions.  In fact if I try that I get an error:

```
In [1031]: A/(A.sum(axis=1)[:,None])
....
ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.
```

Comment: It seems to depend on the scipy version. Using an outdated version, this actually worked as expected for me where the division of two sparse vectors returned a sparse vector. After all, if the dividend has an empty cell, result should be 0 in this cell anyway. For a newer version of scipy, the same line returns a dense numpy matrix...