# Numpy (1, N) dimension to (N,) dimension conversion

Tags: python, numpy

Here 
I got the first row from a numpy matrix

```
firstRow = (allEigenVectors.T)[0, :]
```

where firstRow.shape  is (1,784)

how can I convert it into (784,) shape ?

Comment: use numpy.transpose

Comment: What does `type(firstRow)` give? It sounds like you may be using `np.matrix`, which is usually a terrible idea.

Comment: If `allEigenVectors` is a `np.matrix`, you need something like `.A1` -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array