# In numpy, how can I transform a one-line matrix as an array?

Tags: numpy

I have a matrix `m = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`.

I extract a vector `v = m[0] + m[1]`, so that now `v == [[5, 7, 9]]`. The vector's shape is `(1, 3)`, meaning it's considered a matrix, not a vector. How can I make `v` an actual vector, i.e something of shape `(3,)`?

I tried to use `np.asarray(v)` and `np.array(v)` but they don't do what I want.

Comment: `arr.A1`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3337301/901925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the shortest would be

```
m.A.sum(0)
# array([5, 7, 9])
```

This converts to `array` before summing.

If you are starting from an 1xN `matrix` like `v`:

```
v.A1
# array([5, 7, 9])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.squeeze(np.asarray(v))`. So you *first* convert to an array (which other than matrices can have arbitrary n dimensions), *then* get rid of the extra dimension.

...or avoid using `np.matrix` in the first place, sparing you the extra step.