# cannot convert (N, 1) array to (N,)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a (200, 1) matrix, and I need to convert it to (200,)

```
y = np.matrix(np.append(np.zeros(200), np.ones(200))).T
```

The shape of y is (200,1)

I tried flattening the matrix:

```
c = y.flatten()
```

and I got a shape of (1,200)

Then I tried accessing the first element of the matrix,

```
c[0].shape
```

and I still get shape (1, 200)

How can I convert the original matrix into (200,)

Comment: [Numpy matrix to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array) - an old SO on this topic, with recent additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `y.A1`

```
>>> y = np.matrix(np.identity(3))
>>> y
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
>>> y.A1
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `np.matrix` and according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html),

> class numpy.matrix[source] Returns a matrix from an array-like object, or from a string of data. **A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations.**

Thus, the dimension of `c` remains to be 2 after you call [`matrix.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html#numpy.matrix.flatten). (Note that [`matrix.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html#numpy.matrix.flatten)

> return a copy of the matrix, flattened to a (1, N) matrix where N is the number of elements in the original matrix.

One solution: use `np.array` in

```
y = np.array(np.append(np.zeros(200), np.ones(200))).T
```