# Numpy matrix flattens to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am having issues flatting the following matrix into an array

```
np.matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
```

More generally this matrix will be `n,1` shape

The goal is to get it to be in a `3,` form like `[1, 2, 3]` however I am finding that difficult. Every operation I can find returns a matrix or does not work.

```
x = np.matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
x.flatten()
>>>matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
x.ravel()
>>>matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
x.ravel()[0,:]
>>>matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
np.reshape(x, 3)
>>>matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
x.flatten()[0]
>>>matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

How can I get this one row-ed matrix into a vector?

Comment: what is a "matrix"? how can i reproduce your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array

Comment: The use of the `numpy.matrix` class is discouraged, and it will likely be removed in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to an array. Matrix objects are 2-dimensional by definition.

```
np.array(x).flatten()
```

Alternatively, as mentioned by @hpaulj, matrix objects have `A` and `A1` defined that will return the array object (flattened for `A1`)

```
x.A1
```

Comment: Or a short cut to this: `x.A1`